# MySQL, C++, Windows XP: mysql_init() throws an exception

Tags: mysql

The code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 MYSQL* mysql = mysql_init(NULL);

 getchar();

 mysql_close(mysql);

 return 0;
}
```

throws an exception "Access violation reading location 0x0...04" during the call to "mysql_init(NULL)".
I cannot figure out a possible reason of it - I don't even connect to any server yet - it just the initialization.

Comment: Do you have any includes? Do you have any macros defined?

Comment: includes: <winsock.h>, <mysql.h>, <cstdio>. Just default definitions: WIN32, _DEBUG, _CONSOLE. Linking against libmysqld.lib.

Comment: replaced "<winsock.h>" by "<my_global.h>" - result is the same.

Comment: No real help, but when doing C++ you might also want to look into http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-cpp.html

Comment: MySQL dropped aside. PostgreSQL worked without any problems. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **libmysql.lib** to your input linkers.

If you are using Visual Studio, add **libmysql.lib** to all folders in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.16299.0\um

Next, in Visual Studio go to **Project > Properties > Linker > Input**

Under Additional Dependencies, **hit the arrow and click edit**

On the top box, add **libmysql.lib** within the list.

Click **OK, Apply, and OK**

Link: https://github.com/udan11/samp-plugin-sql/blob/master/lib/mysql/libmysql.lib

Comment: It was 8 years ago ^^. I suppose there would be compilation error if any definitions would be missing - not runtime.